# jQuery works only in firefox or safari/chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mozilla

I have this strange bug. My jQuery code works in Firefox, and also when I paste it in Safari's or Chrome's console.

I have it loaded first, and I'm pretty sure it reads it cause alert is showing.
Do you see anything wrong with the code that might affect this issue?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var questionOne = $('.questions').find('.question').eq(0);
    questionOne.removeClass('hide');
});
```

I don't have any kind of errors in console.
I tried loading the script I think in every possible way that's on the internet.

Comment: Seems syntactically correct, though you are removing hide in both the if and the else case...  The else doesn't make sense.  It doesn't have the class, as per your if being false.

Comment: @Taplar it's still kinda work in progress, but I shorten it now to do what it should.

Comment: @Camila can you replace the `$` with `jQuery` and see if that does anything? It might be because of some conflicts with the `$` character.

Comment: Nope, still nothing. But as it works pefect in console, is there some logic on that end? @AR7

Comment: Sounds like a race condition. Are the `.questions` / `.question` elements loaded dynamically (eg via AJAX)? If you view the page source (not the DOM inspector, the actual source), do you see those elements?

Comment: Could you try writing the element found to the console and see what comes up?  console.log($('.questions').find('.question').get(0));

Comment: They are loaded dynamically, I used js partials to loop through answers and questions. @TomMulkins I get my question!

Comment: I see.  It's appearing as undefined because it can't find those elements by class name when the page loads.  You'll likely need to use an event handler to get the current state of your generated elements using .on().  See http://api.jquery.com/on/

It would help to see all of the code creating these too.

Comment: @TomMulkins I actually figured out that I had this function set timeout that was doing this. it's this:
 function queueRender() {
  var _this = this;
  if(typeof settings.queueRenderTimeout !== "undefined") {
   clearTimeout(settings.queueRenderTimeout)
  }
//   render();
  settings.queueRenderTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
   render();
  }, settings.debounce);
 }
If I remove it it breaks whole page, if I have then it doesn't load jQuery. Can I remove it somehow so that my code works?

Comment: Please try to set up a running snippet on here or re-create the scenario on another service like jsfiddle or codepen so we can see the error. That or provide a demonstrative sample of the HTML / CSS for your page.

Comment: I think Google Chrome Console doesn't support jQuery. You can only write pure javascript inside the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems right, but as other may have said that if object ".questions" have not been rendered then you won't be able to find it.
I had a problem like that before and this is what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var Counter = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function () {
            Counter += 20;
            var questionOne = $('.questions').find('.question').eq(0);
            questionOne.removeClass('hide');
            if (questionOne.length > 0)
                Counter = 3000;
            if (Counter >= 3000)
                clearInterval(interval)
        }, 2);
    });
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        var questionOne = $('.questions').find('.question').eq(0);
        questionOne.removeClass('hide');
    }, 100);
});
```